# Is there any way to pause redis server?

Tags: node.js, redis

We figure out our node application with redis server.
But the problem is that when we restart node server we can not get any key expire from redis during server is not running so we can not do any operation on particular key.

so please help me if any way to solve this problem

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/client-pause

You can try this

Comment: Command should be CLIENT PAUSE timeout

Comment: Hopefully accept my answer & give a upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this : redis.io/commands/client-pause 
Command should be

```
CLIENT PAUSE timeout
```